# How to fix the error data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, meta, metafor

I am trying to perform a egger's test with the following function:

```
eggers.test<-function(data){data<-data
eggers<-metabias(data)
intercept<-as.numeric(eggers$estimate[1])
intercept<-round(intercept,digits=3)
se.intercept<-eggers$estimate[2]
lower.intercept<-as.numeric(intercept-1.96*se.intercept)
lower.intercept<-round(lower.intercept,digits = 2)
higher.intercept<-as.numeric(intercept+1.96*se.intercept)
higher.intercept<-round(higher.intercept,digits = 2)
ci.intercept<-paste(lower.intercept,"-",higher.intercept)
ci.intercept<-gsub(" ", "", ci.intercept, fixed = TRUE)
intercept.pval<-as.numeric(eggers$p.value)
intercept.pval<-round(intercept.pval,digits=5)
eggers.output<-data.frame(intercept,ci.intercept, intercept.pval)
names(eggers.output)<-c("intercept","95%CI","p-value")
title<-"Results of Egger's test of the intercept"
print(title)
print(eggers.output)
}
```

Only when I am at the step:

eggers.output<-data.frame(intercept,ci.intercept, intercept.pval)

R gives the following error: 
   Error in data.frame(intercept, ci.intercept, intercept.pval) :

arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you are using arguments with a different number of rows. If you want to use `data.frame()`, you need to use arguments with an equal number of rows. Check the number of rows of `intercept`, `ci.intercept` and `intercept.pval` and it should show you where the difference is.